# When importing tkinter's "messagebox" module, does the "import tkinter.messagebox" syntax not work?

Tags: python, import, tkinter, messagebox

Since the "messagebox" is a module in the "tkinter" package, why do I have to use

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

instead of

```
import tkinter.messagebox
```

I was under the impression that to import a module within a package I would have to use the following syntax:

```
import package_name.module_name
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, generally speaking you are correct: `messagebox` is a module in the `tkinter` package, and with any normal Python module you should be able to import it with either syntax. However, it seems that tkinter does some magic upon import (some sort of caching maybe), possibly for performance / memory usage reasons. Notice for example, that if you *first* do `from tkinter import messagebox` and then `import tkinter.messagebox`, the second syntax does in fact work.

Comment: Also try `import tkinter`, and compare a `dir(tkinter)` before you do `from tkinter import messagebox` and after. So to summarize: Your understanding of Python modules / packages and imports is correct, this is some Tkinter-specific weirdness.

Comment: ...and then you have `import tkMessageBox`

Comment: Interestingly, it works on 3.4, so it may have been a bug

Answer (score 2):

Importing tkinter.messagebox does work *(at least in should, and does in 3.4, maybe there might be a bug in other releases)*, but it is imported as `tkinter.messagebox`, which is tedious and lengthy to write, and if the rest of `tkinter` is being used, it is pointless to do, seeing as `tkinter.messagebox` will have already been indirectly imported. So generally `from tkinter import messagebox` is considered easier, and does not loose much, if any readability.

Answer (score 0):

messagebox, along with some other modules like filedialog, does not automatically get imported when you import tkinter. Import it explicitly, using as and/or from as desired. check below 3 examples for better clarification-

```
    >>> import tkinter
    >>> tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'
```

.

```
    >>> import tkinter.messagebox
    >>> tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')

'ok'
```

.

```
 >>> from tkinter import messagebox
    >>> messagebox.showinfo(message='hi')

'ok'
```